# ReactNative ScrollView inside a View

Tags: android, react-native, android-scrollview

Im trying to make a scrollview inside a View in ReactNative. For some reason i cant scroll in the ScrollView.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Text>Top</Text>
        </View>
        <ScrollView >
          <Text>Line 1</Text>
          <Text>Line 2</Text>
          <Text>Line 3</Text>
          <Text>Line 4</Text>
          <Text>Line 5</Text>
          <Text>Line 6</Text>
          <Text>Line 7</Text>
          ...
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

What is wrong here? Im testing on Android

Thanks,
Magnus

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548664/react-native-scroll-view-not-scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't forget to import scrollview from react native like this :import {
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

```js
    render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}> // style in firstview
            <View>
              <Text>Top</Text>
            </View>
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.Scroll}>// and give style in scrollview
              <Text>Line 1</Text>
              <Text>Line 2</Text>
              <Text>Line 3</Text>
              <Text>Line 4</Text>
              <Text>Line 5</Text>
              <Text>Line 6</Text>
              <Text>Line 7</Text>
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        );
      }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        // alignItems: 'center'
    },
    Scroll: {
      height: 1000,
      paddingVertical: 30,
  }
});
```

Comment: Most upvoted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548664/react-native-scroll-view-not-scrolling) is more flexible , because with 1000 is kind of weird when you don't know screen height .

Answer (score 5):

You should give the ScrollView a height. From the example in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html);

```
<ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
...
...
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    height: 300,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this wasn't exactly what i was looking for but it led me to the flex layout.
Thanks.