# React-Native, Scroll View Not Scrolling

Tags: react-native

When I wrap content like this example below, it scrolls Perfectly..

```
return(
    <ScrollView>
        <Text> TEST </Text>
        <Text> TEST </Text>
        <Text> TEST </Text>
        <Text> TEST </Text>
        ...
    </ScrollView>
);
```

However, whenever I wrap it in another View, It will not scroll.

```
return(
    <View>
        <ScrollView>
            <Text> TEST </Text>
            <Text> TEST </Text>
            <Text> TEST </Text>
            <Text> TEST </Text>
            ...    
        </SCrollView>
    </View>
);
```

Is there some sort of fix to this. I am trying to put a nav bar header above all of the content, couldn't really figure it out though.

Answer (score 84):

It's a typo:
Your closing `ScrollView` tag is: `</SCrollView>` rather than `</ScrollView>`.
You also need to add a style to the `View` container, here's an example of what it should look like:

```
return(
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ScrollView>
      <Text> TEST </Text>
      <Text> TEST </Text>
      <Text> TEST </Text>
      <Text> TEST </Text>
      ...    
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: adding  flex:1 indeed fixes it ! thankyou. this should be accepted answer

Comment: this answer is incomplete. the requirements for a working scrollview appear to be flex:1 on the outer view and flexGrow:1 on the contentContainerStyle for the scrollview.

Comment: this answer used to be correct 3 years ago, things might change

Comment: doesn't work on android, i have tested pretty much every method here

Comment: @NicolasSilva I was about to say the same think and GabeRogan answer was the one that worked

Answer (score 49):

Try next code:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
  <Text> TEST </Text>
  <Text> TEST </Text>
  <Text> TEST </Text>
  <Text> TEST </Text>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: came here looking for the solution like multiple times and every time this answer helped me. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't really work for me. Could you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437251/unable-to-scroll-in-scrollview

Comment: If at all anybody is using this with `contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, flex: 1 }}`, remove `flex: 1`. That's what was making the view unscrollable for me.

Comment: Remove `flex: 1` from `contentContainerStyle` it brokes the whole thing. And add `flexGrow: 1`.

Comment: This should have the check mark for the accepted answer

Answer (score 38):

If your `ScrollView` is within something that handles touch (`Pressable`, `TouchableWithoutFeedback` etc) then you either need to stop the touch event propagating up to that parent handler or else the `ScrollView` won't handle the touch event and therefore won't scroll.

[This can be done either with `onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49918614/827129) or by wrapping the children in an element which itself handles the touch event (e.g. `Pressable`):

```
return (
  <ScrollView>
    <Pressable>
      <Text>This is scrollable</Text>
    <Pressable>
    <Pressable>
      <Text>As is this</Text>
    <Pressable>
  </ScrollView>
);
```

Comment: Adding `<Pressable>` did the trick for me!

Comment: Thanks man. I was having `PanResponder` as parent and for some reason my `Scrollview` was not scrolling even after passing true to `onStartShouldSetResponder` on iOS. This helped me to fix the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to have helped @Rohit.

Comment: Thanks! I'm, using a wrapper with a press evento to hide the keyboard, ant this was making the scroll don't works.

Comment: Thanks man! Pressable works for me also. I just used one Pressable component as a parent container for all my items. Didn't have to use many

Answer (score 24):

Try adding `style={{flex:1}}` to `<View>` and `<ScrollView>` components. You also have a typo on your code: `</SCrollView>` in line 9. An example code will look like this:

```
<View style={{backgroundColor:'white', flex:1}}>
    <NavigationBar title="Title" />
    <ScrollView style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
            <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center'}}>
                <RegisterForm />
            </View>
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: in latest react version you cannot use  `style` just use `contentContainerStyle`

Comment: This doesn't really work for me. Could you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437251/unable-to-scroll-in-scrollview

Answer (score 14):

Another solution is to add a height property to the parent View container.  This sometimes works well when calculating the height against the screen height.

```
render () {
  const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height

  return(
    <View style={{height: screenHeight}}>
      <ScrollView>
        <Text> TEST </Text>
        <Text> TEST </Text>
        <Text> TEST </Text>
        <Text> TEST </Text>
           ...    
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: its work well for me when  run this  project on snack as web

Comment: I tried adding height: 80%. However, when the keypad is open I can scroll but not to the end. and if I add height: 100%, I am not able to scroll at all. Could you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437251/unable-to-scroll-in-scrollview

Comment: adding style={{flex: 1, height: screenHight}} worked for me........!!! thanks !!!

Answer (score 5):

I have tried all of these solutions and none were working. Then I just fully restarted the app and the metro server and everything worked fine.

Comment: Amazing how often this works. You spend hours working on something, in frustration you start the whole shebang and wow it all works. Something isn't right with metro (expo metro), but what?

Comment: I can't believe I have wasted so many hours on finding solution instead of restarting my app again. Everything worked fine after killing the app and restarting metro server again. Thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried above mentioned answers, but it didtn't work for me. Default `ScrollView` works well in the `ios`, but in the `android` it is not.

I have tried `nestedScrollEnabled={true}` as mentioned in the document [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#nestedscrollenabled-android) it works well in `android`.

**Note:** For `ios`, after adding `nestedScrollEnabled={true}` along with `scrollEnabled={true}` works fine. Refer [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollenabled)

```js
<View style={styles.catBody}>
  <ScrollView 
    scrollEnabled={true}
    nestedScrollEnabled={true}
  >
    <Text style={styles.catBodyText}>{props.item.description}</Text>
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Evan Siroky has answered above it's working well I'm just adding on thing for a auto height in case you don't want to reserve the space

```
render () {
  const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height
  return(
    <View style={{ Height: "auto", maxHeight: screenHeight}}>
      <ScrollView>
        <Text> TEST </Text>
        <Text> TEST </Text>
        <Text> TEST </Text>
        <Text> TEST </Text>
           ...    
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: I tried adding height: auto but then I can't scroll at it. It works partially with height: 80% tho. Could you take a look here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437251/unable-to-scroll-in-scrollview

Comment: I think so you can fix this issue by following below tips:
1)Adjusting ScrollView tag position most probably it will go above your condition directly inside <></>
2)By adjusting height and maxHeight property and flex property

Answer (score 2):

removing contentContainerStyle prop from the ScrollView has fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issues, it got solved by removing height/width if set to '100%'.

Just adding here if someone faces the same issues. :D

Answer (score 0):

Set nestedScrollEnabled as true for Hybrid Android + react app as it might be issue with gesture/click for scrolling issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just if anyone is as desperate as I was:
My view was inside a `StackNavigator`. In the StackNavigator you can assign a default `cardStyle`. This card style needs `height: "100%"`.

For me this was the case but I had overwritten it within the cardStyle of the Stack.Screen definition.

See this working example:

```js
// This is the stack navigator

<ModalStack.Navigator screenOptions={() => ({
    cardStyle: {height: "100%"}
});}}>
    <ModalStack.Screen name={ScreenItemDetail} options={{
        // cardStyle: {} be sure to not override card style again! 
        
    }} component={ItemDetailScreen} />

    // ...

</ModalStack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me issue was using percentage in width and margin of items.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that my screen would only scroll if I scrolled from clickable elements.

I've found that wrapping the `ScrollView`'s content in a `TouchableOpacity` and `TouchableWithoutFeedback` was the neatest way to get my scrolling working well without any strange clicking side effects.

In the end you end up with this:

```
<ScrollView {...scrollViewPropsAndStylesEtc}>
  <TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      {content}
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  </TouchableOpacity>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The top answer, which is correct, advises the following to stop the touch event from propagating up to the ScrollView parent:

> wrapping the children in an element which itself handles the touch event (e.g. Pressable)

I found that some components that handle the touch event do not suffice. In my case it was `RectButton` from `react-native-gesture-handler`.

In this situation you have two options:

1. Wrap all `ScrollView` children into a single `Pressable` - it doesn't even need an `onPress` prop.
2. Replacing touchable children that are not `Pressable` with `Pressable` (or perhaps another touchable component that does work, I haven't tried others).

Answer (score -1):

Just add ScrollView as parent View if it's still not working for you...just restart your app or server and your ScrollView will work fine. Because sometimes our app freezes for no reason.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I think the best way of doing this is to put all requires inside an array and map this array.

```
const images = [
  require('../your/path/here'),
  require('../other/image/here'),
  ...
];

return ( {images.map((image) => <Image ... source={image} />)
```

note that if you want it as a background image with other elements above the image, you may use BackgroundImage and either render elements for each image or position absolute the image map and zIndex it behind all things