# How to handle ScrollView inside a Pressable in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, uiscrollview, styled-components

Right now, I am creating a modal with items inside the modal to scroll. However, I am noticing the touch function is being extremely obscured and not passing through appropriately. With this current implementation, scrolling on the ScrollView is not working. I am just trying to have this scrollview inside the modal, I have set it up so that the modal can be pressable inside and an outside press of the modal will cause it to close. So I need to pass the proper touchable properties down.

Some resources and previous stack overflow pages I was looking at was:

[React-Native, Scroll View Not Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548664/react-native-scroll-view-not-scrolling)

```
 return (
    <Container {...props}>
      <BottomModal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}>
        <CenterView onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}>
          <ModalContent>
            <ModalHeader>
              <CloseButtonContainer>
                <Pressable onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}>
                  <CloseButton
                    name="times-circle"
                    type={vectorIconTypes.MEDIUM}
                  />
                </Pressable>
              </CloseButtonContainer>
              <TitleContainer>
                <TitleText>{title}</TitleText>
              </TitleContainer>
            </ModalHeader>
            <ModalList>
              <ScrollContainer>
                <LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                  <TitleText>Newest</TitleText>
                  <CheckBox />
                </LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                <LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                  <TitleText>Points High to Low</TitleText>
                  <CheckBox />
                </LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                <LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                  <TitleText>Brands A to Z</TitleText>
                  <CheckBox />
                </LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                <LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                  <TitleText>Brands A to Z</TitleText>
                  <CheckBox />
                </LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                <LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                  <TitleText>Brands A to Z</TitleText>
                  <CheckBox />
                </LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                <LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                  <TitleText>Brands A to Z</TitleText>
                  <CheckBox />
                </LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                <LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                  <TitleText>Brands A to Z</TitleText>
                  <CheckBox />
                </LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                <LeftTextRightCheckBox>
                  <TitleText>Brands A to Z</TitleText>
                  <CheckBox />
                </LeftTextRightCheckBox>
              </ScrollContainer>
            </ModalList>
          </ModalContent>
        </CenterView>
      </BottomModal>
</Container>


...  

const Container = styled.View`
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
`;

const BottomModal = styled.Modal`
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
`;

const CenterView = styled.Pressable`
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 100%;
`;

const ModalContent = styled.Pressable`
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  height: 300px;
`;

const ModalHeader = styled.View`
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 60px;
`;

const ModalList = styled(ScrollView).attrs(() => ({
  contentContainerStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator: true,
  persistentScrollbar: true,
}))`
  border: solid pink 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
`;
```

Answer (score 5):

My question was answered perfectly in the same link I had in my question. All credit goes to freddrivett.

> If your ScrollView is within something that handles touch (Pressable,
> TouchableWithoutFeedback etc) then you either need to stop the touch
> event propagating up to that parent handler or else the ScrollView
> won't handle the touch event and therefore won't scroll.
>
> This can be done either with onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true} or
> by wrapping the children in an element which itself handles the touch
> event (e.g. Pressable):
>
> ```
>     <Pressable>
>       <Text>This is scrollable</Text>
>     <Pressable>
>     <Pressable>
>       <Text>As is this</Text>
>     <Pressable>   </ScrollView> );
> ```

Comment: If that's the case, you should probably close your question as a duplicate of that one

Comment: How do I do that?