# React Native, cant use ScrollView inside BottomSheet

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I've implemented a search function and page on my app. I open BottomSheets for more information, like a DataTable, but I just cant use a ScrollView inside my BottomSheet, and so not everything fits on my BottomSheet.

```
import { Div, Text, Button, Input, Image, ScrollDiv } from "react-native-magnus";
import { useState, useCallback, useMemo, useRef } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import React from "react";
import Carousel from "react-native-carousel-control";
import BottomSheet from "react-native-gesture-bottom-sheet";
import env from "../env";
import AddToMealsModal from "./AddToMealsModal";
import { DataTable } from 'react-native-paper';
import { ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import {nutrientsNameAndCategory} from "../utils/nutrientsNameAndCategory";


const FoodInformationModal = (props) => {
    const bottomSheet = React.useRef();
    var nutrientsCarouselItems = props.nutrients.map(nutrient => {
        if (nutrient.amount != 0) {
            return (
                <Div style={{
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    borderRadius: 5,
                }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{
                            height: 100
                        }}
                        onPress={() => {{
                            alert(nutrientsNameAndCategory[nutrient.nutrientId].name + ": " + nutrient.amount + " mg" )
                        }
                    }}
                    >
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4ph00078vpcs4nx4kpn" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/a.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4pk00208vpcu5o7a7uj" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/e.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4pl00278vpcexyv0pse" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/k.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4pm00338vpcliks7a0n" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/b1.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4pn00398vpcx6ia3vnv" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/b2.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4pt00858vpcdzhjl669" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/b5.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4pn00458vpcywk5yrl3" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/b6.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4pq00648vpcc83jye8a" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/b7.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4po00518vpco35ce0jb" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/b12.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4pr00718vpcccjw7qu5" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/ni.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4ps00788vpca8f1l7w3" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/f.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4pv00988vpc709ldv5i" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/ca.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4pv01048vpcye864tyg" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/cl.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4pw01108vpclxaqkyv4" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/mg.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4px01168vpcva8l1fzv" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/p.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4py01228vpcnw9dr9s4" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/kalium.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4pz01288vpcfkpwndxj" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/na.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4q001428vpcyxtz3vn3" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/cr.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4q101488vpcxpw3v0xy" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/cu.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4q201548vpcrifefmwj" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/flour.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4q201608vpc6dmw4mao" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/j.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4q301738vpc8h7y24v5" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/mn.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4q401808vpc7966oalv" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/mo.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4q401878vpci9ixunsd" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/se.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4q501948vpcppnxoaxy" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/zn.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4q301678vpc4keh8u0t" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/fe.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4pp00588vpcsti9l4dx" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/c.png"}}/>}
                        {nutrient.nutrientId == "ckyvcy4pj00148vpcmabjhnp8" && <Image h={100} w={100} source={{uri: "http://" + env.IP + ":4000/images/d.png"}}/>}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </Div> 
                );
        } else {
            return (
                <></>
            )
        }
        })
    if (props.nutrients.length > 2) {
        nutrientsCarouselItems.push(<Div />)
    }
    return (
    <Div>
            <Text style={{
                fontWeight: "700",
                fontSize: 20,
                textAlign: "center",
                marginTop: 10,
            }}>
                {props.name}
            </Text>
            <Text style={{
                fontStyle: "italic",
                fontWeight: "500",
                textAlign: "center",
                marginTop: 10
            }}>
                {props.description}
            </Text>
            <Div style={{
                marginTop: 30,
                height: 100,
            }}>
                <Carousel pageStyle={{
                    width: 100
                }}>
                    {nutrientsCarouselItems}
                </Carousel>
            </Div>
                <ScrollView style={{
                        height: "100%",
                        marginBottom: 100,
                        backgroundColor: "red",
                        margin: 20
                    }}>
                    <DataTable>
                        <DataTable.Header>
                            <DataTable.Title>Nährstoff</DataTable.Title>
                            <DataTable.Title>Kategorie</DataTable.Title>
                            <DataTable.Title numeric>Menge in mg</DataTable.Title>
                        </DataTable.Header>
                    
                        {props.nutrients.map((nutrient) => {
                            if (nutrient.amount != 0) {
                                return (
                                    <DataTable.Row>
                                        <DataTable.Cell>{nutrientsNameAndCategory[nutrient.nutrientId].name}</DataTable.Cell>
                                        <DataTable.Cell>{nutrientsNameAndCategory[nutrient.nutrientId].category}</DataTable.Cell>
                                        <DataTable.Cell numeric>{nutrient.amount}</DataTable.Cell>
                                    </DataTable.Row>
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        )}
                    </DataTable>
                    <Button onPress={() => {
                        bottomSheet.current.show()
                    }}>
                        Hinzufügen
                    </Button>
                </ScrollView>
            <Div style={{
                marginLeft: Dimensions.get("screen").width / 2.8
            }}>
            </Div>
            <BottomSheet hasDraggableIcon ref={bottomSheet} height={Dimensions.get("screen").height * 0.9}>
                <AddToMealsModal id={props.id} name={props.name} nutrients={props.nutrients} description={props.description} navigation={props.navigation} bottomSheet={bottomSheet}/>
            </BottomSheet>
    </Div>
    )
}

export default FoodInformationModal;
```

This is my code for the actual component, which is called in the BottomSheet.

```
<BottomSheet draggable={true} ref={bottomSheet} height={Dimensions.get("screen").height * 0.9} overDragResistanceFactor={10} detached={true}>
   <BottomSheetModal id={clickedInfo.id} name={clickedInfo.name} nutrients={clickedInfo.nutrients} description={clickedInfo.description} isAdd={isAdd} navigation={ navigation } bottomSheet={bottomSheet} /* meals={meals} *//>
</BottomSheet>
```

This is how the BottomSheet is called, in combination with the BottomSheetModal component:

```
import FoodInformationModal from "./FoodInformationModal";
import AddFoodModal from "./AddFoodModal";

export default BottomSheetModal = (props) => {
    if (props.isAdd) {
        return <AddFoodModal bottomSheet={props.bottomSheet} />
    } else {
        return <FoodInformationModal {...props} />
    }
}
```

Does any of you know how to fix this?

[How it looks like with enough space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOSBm.png)

[How it looks like with not enough space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTHmc.png)

Comment: What is the issue here? If it is that you can't use a ScrollView, and you want to, can you say why it's not working, or give an error message?

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, its just not working. I just cant scroll and there isnt even the scroll bar at the right.

Comment: What have you tried? Do any of the answers here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548664/react-native-scroll-view-not-scrolling

Comment: Wrapping the Table parts into `<Pressable>` was the solution for me. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Native, Scroll View Not Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548664/react-native-scroll-view-not-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  component provided by the library

```
    import React from "react";
    import {View} from "react-native";
    import BottomSheet, { BottomSheetScrollView } from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet";

    const App = () => {
      return (
        <View>
          <BottomSheet
            ref={sheetRef}
            index={1}
            snapPoints={snapPoints}
            onChange={handleSheetChange}>
            <BottomSheetScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
              {/*Place your views here*/}
            </BottomSheetScrollView>
          </BottomSheet>
        </View>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

import {
ScrollView,
FlatList
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import ScrollView and FlatList from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
it will work