# react-native buttons and scrolling not working

Tags: react-native

when I run my react native app the buttons and scrolling are not working, but after i make any change in any file, scrolling and those buttons get started to work. can someone help me with this issue

Comment: Please add some Code and what u have tried to fix. U give Not many infos.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

read this article please, hopefully, you will get your answer:

```
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548664/react-native-scroll-view-not-scrolling][1]
```